# Same math and numbers different answers?

Tags: c++, math, c++17

im writing a simple program that you give a number of days and it gives back the number of years weeks and days that equal to the numbers of days you give.
but i noticed that you can get two different answers even tho when i checked the math it makes sense in both cases .
can someone please please explain to me why the answers are different and which one is correct

```
    #include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int y;
    int d,w;
    int Days;

    cin>>d;

    y=d/365;
    int LessThanAYearDays = d%365;
    Days=LessThanAYearDays%7;
    w=LessThanAYearDays/7;
    int SameDays = d%7;
    

    cout<<"answer1 is : "<<y<<" "<<w<<" "<<Days<< "\n";
    cout<<"answer2 is : "<<y<<" "<<w<<" "<<SameDays<< "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Days` is `(d % 365) % 7` and `SameDays` is `d % 7` hence the different result

Comment: "when i checked the math it makes sense in both cases" <-- if `(x%7)` and `(y%7)` give different results, it's because `x` and `y` are not the same. Did you check that?

Comment: "p.s. every month is considered to be 30 days and every year is considered to be 365 days" << I don't know what to make of this sentence. You can consider what you want, but if you rely on `12 * 30 == 365` somewhere in your calculations, you should expect weird results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not an exact multiple of weeks in a year, so you are displaying different things. They *will be the same* in years divisible by 7.

E.g. Assume that a given year starts on a Tuesday.

- `Days` corresponds to how many days past the last Tuesday you are.
- `SameDays` corresponds to what day you are on.

See also the distinction that `std` makes between a [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), which is a count of time, and a [`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point), which is a count of time *since a particular date*.